# To sort a table with linked data

Tags: numbers

There is a Numbers document with 3 sheets: **first** (2 columns), **second** (1 column), and **third** (1 column).

**second**:

```
sun
grass
sea
```

**third**:

```
yellow
green
blue
```

**first**:

```
Column A             | Column B
=second::Table 1::A1 | =third::Table 1::A1
=second::Table 1::A2 | =third::Table 1::A2
=second::Table 1::A3 | =third::Table 1::A3
```

which results to:

```
Column A | Column B
sun      | yellow
grass    | green
sea      | blue
```

Fine. But if I try to sort ascending the table on **second** sheet, grass become yellow, sea green, and sun blue:

```
Column A | Column B
grass    | yellow
sea      | green
sun      | blue
```

The same issue happens if I try to sort the table on the **third** sheet instead:

```
Column A | Column B
sun      | blue
grass    | green
sea      | yellow
```

What do I need to fix/workaround this issue?

I have read many forum threads at Apple Discussions and there were suggestions to use `LOOKUP` and `INDIRECT` functions, but I have not realized how to use them here and whether they are suitable for this particular case at all.

Comment: One way of doing what you want would be to add an ID number for each row to all of those tables and use either of the LOOKUP functions (LOOKUP, VLOOKUP, or XLOOKUP). You would then pull in values from the second and third tables to the first table using either of these functions and the ID number for the respective row rather than the cell addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the screenshot of an example utilizing the [LOOKUP function](https://support.apple.com/guide/functions/lookup-ffa597dc7b/13.0/web/1.0):

[image]

All objects are pulled into the table First using the same formula except that each formula looks up the ID in its row in the table Second. A similar formula is used to pull in the colors to the table First by referring to the columns in the table Third.

Then, the contents of the table First would not be changed even if the objects in the table Second or the colors in the table Third are sorted or moved within. However, the rows in either the table Second or the Third should always be sorted or moved as a whole, i.e. along with the IDs as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]